# django-admin.py not working properly in powershell

Tags: python, django, powershell, python-3.x, django-1.6

I'm new to Django, so this has been a learning process so far.  Basically, following the Django tutorial I tried to run `django-admin.py startproject mysite` and got [this output](http://postimg.org/image/uijlbpct1/).

If I try to run the command with `py -3` or `py` I get [this](http://postimg.org/image/x15acdyj9/).

However, if I run `django-admin.py startproject mysite` in cmd it works.

Running the command with `py -3` or `py` in cmd gives the same results as powershell.  The kicker, for me anyway, is when I use the full filepath, `py -3 (or just py) C:\Python33\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite`, in powershell, it works...

My path includes the python script directory and I've set the .py file association.  I'm only referencing the C:\Python33\Scripts directory in the path since I have both 2.7 and 3.3 installed currently.

I don't know why powershell won't cooperate with Django.

Edit: I am running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already added the the file path for the Scripts folder to your environment variables in Powershell as well as added .py file association, which it sounds like you already have, then you actually don't need to have the .py,so instead of `django-admin.py startproject mysite`, you just need to type `django-admin startproject mysite` I think.